# How can I view iOS App Store URL before release?

Tags: ios, url

We have an app that's 'Pending Developer Release', i.e. we've passed review and are ready to go. But Marketing would like the App Store URL before public release for obvious reasons. There used to be a "View in App Store" option on App Store Connect (As older posts note), but it seems to have been removed sometime in 2018.

Is there a way to view the URL w/o releasing the app?

Answer (score 0):

You can have Apple id under App Information Section and replace the id with any of the Live Application app store URL.